# What are essential prime implicants in this example?

Tags: karnaugh-map

F(A,B,C,D) = Sum (0,2,3,5,7,8,9,10,11,13,15).

The prime implicants are represented in different colours as below and the equation of the function is found to be F = B'D' + BD + CD + AB'.

[image]

I tried to identify all the essential prime implicants (epi) and all the terms which made them epi.

Can you tell me if I found all the terms and epi?

1st epi: B'D'

Terms that made B'D' epi: 0,2

2nd epi: BD

Terms that made BD epi: 5

3rd epi: CD

Terms that made CD epi: 3

Comment: Btw the green ones are covered together. I just couldn't make visualise it on my laptop

Comment: Yeah, I've got it already from the expression

Comment: I believe you have got all of the epi's. But there is one prime implicant you have missed - AD (not that you need it for the minimal expression though)